# Input 'ref' passed int32 expected ref type while building NodeDef

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I want to multiply 2 tensors, so I used lambda layer in Keras and use the target 2 tensors as the input to the lambda layer as follows

```js
def get_col_att(tensors):

    for i in range(num_samples):
        global t
        t=tf.assign(t,i)
        x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[0], t)
        print("tensors[1]:",tensors[1])
        y = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tensors[1], t)
        print("x shape",x.shape,"y shape",y.shape)
        ab=tf.transpose(y)

        Ecol=tf.reshape(tf.tensordot(x,ab,axes=1),[1,M,C])
        if i==0: 
            all_col_attention=tf.Variable(initial_value=Ecol)
        else:
            all_col_attention=tf.concat([all_col_attention,Ecol],0)

    print("all_col_attention",all_col_attention)
    return all_col_attention

total_alpha_sel_np=Lambda(get_col_att)([Hq,cols_last_hidden])
```

But it gives the following error

```js
Input 'ref' passed int32 expected ref type while building NodeDef
```

And I figured out where is the error is and it's in the following line

```js
all_col_attention=tf.Variable(initial_value=Ecol)
```

and also it because of the Ecol
so i replaced Ecol(3-d) with y(2-d) and also with tensors1. And it's working for tensors[1] but not for the y.The following are the shapes of tensors

`x shape (13, 80) y shape (12, 80)
tf.tensordot(x,ab,axes=1) Tensor("lambda_42/Reshape:0", shape=(1, 13, 12), dtype=float32)
x shape (13, 80) y shape (12, 80)
tf.tensordot(x,ab,axes=1) Tensor("lambda_42/Reshape_2:0", shape=(1, 13, 12), dtype=float32)
x shape (13, 80) y shape (12, 80)
tf.tensordot(x,ab,axes=1) Tensor("lambda_42/Reshape_4:0", shape=(1, 13, 12), dtype=float32)
all_col_attention Tensor("lambda_42/concat_1:0", shape=(3, 13, 12), dtype=float32)
x shape (13, 80) y shape (12, 80)
tf.tensordot(x,ab,axes=1) Tensor("lambda_42/Reshape_6:0", shape=(1, 13, 12), dtype=float32)`

Please help me on this :-(

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the problem is not with the shape of the tensor. The error is with the lambda layer. the lambda layer in Keras is calling the function two times because of the training and validation graph.

There are two graphs which are constructed. One for training. The other for validation.
You shouldn't use some global variable to save some internal state.
Create a custom layer which outputs two tensors.

[Reference](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5648)

Comment: Thanx Amila I fixed the issue by passing all_col_attention for the second call without computing it for the second time because the weights are shared across the training and validation graphs.